# How do you get DirectShow to play a video from a resource?

Tags: windows, directshow, native

I'm extending an application to play one of several videos on a control in a dialog. Starting with the Windowless sample, I've got this working, though the videos have to be separate files from the main executable.

The ideal scenario from a packaging standpoint is for the videos to be included with the executable as resources.  I did a bit of googling for this, and there's a fair amount of "somebody should do this", and several pointers to the Async sample, though it's not clear how to get where I want from there.

Does anybody know a simple way to do this? It doesn't seem like this is a corner case, and I'm a bit surprised that this wasn't in the box.

Comment: Are you looking for information on how to do the packaging or the playback?

Comment: Playback; I was planning to just embed the WMV file as a resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for ***[Async Filter Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd317573(VS.85).aspx)*** in the DirectShow SDK, It has impl something called CMemStream which can stream data (read: media) from memory.
[more info on this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/mikewasson/archive/2008/01/24/async-filter-sample.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you extract the video from the EXE/DLL and store it in the temp path? Then play the temp file.

Comment: One of the reasons I want to embed the videos is so I can cache them in memory. The current solution has a ~750ms delay when switching videos, which is rather jarring for the user, since it ties up the UI thread.

Comment: But you could extract them all to the temp path on startup in a background thread ... (or programdata)