# Rendering from memory using DirectShow

Tags: c#, video, directshow, directshow.net

I'm very new to DirectShow and I'm looking for a way to render a video which is already loaded into the memory using DirectShow.NET. How can I do that? I'd be thankful even if you give me a highlight of the path.

Comment: I have a Buffer Source filter (32-bit only).  It is a source filter that contains a COM interface you can call to put data into it.  If you want it, let me know.

Answer (score 5):

There is no standard component to play from memory data, however [Async Filter Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317573) from Windows SDK implements exactly this.

> The application reads the file into memory at the specified rate and plays the file.

Note that the filter requires, however, expects some C++ development from you.

See also:

- [On Async Filter Sample](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikewasson/archive/2008/01/24/async-filter-sample.aspx)
- [Play video file from a memory stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8890353/play-video-file-from-a-memory-stream/8904412#8904412)
- [How do you get DirectShow to play a video from a resource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530998/how-do-you-get-directshow-to-play-a-video-from-a-resource/692625#692625)

Comment: Hi Roman,  I tryed the Async Filter Sample , but I don't know how to set the per sample size of Output Pin , IID_IAMBufferNegotiation or IID_IAMStreamConfig?  CLSID_AudioInputDeviceCategory work fine ,but Async Filter will get NOINTERFACE, maybe I can write a custom Audio Source Filter support that ?