# C# How Can I Play A Video From A Memory Stream Using DirectShow(quartz.dll)?

Tags: c#, video, directshow

I have a C# Visual Studio WinForms .NET app that plays video using the QuartzTypeLib (quartz.dll). With the code I've written, I can play any video file from the hard drive.

Here's the code at the top that executes when the app starts:

```
    public const int WS_CHILD = 0x40000000;
    public const int WS_CLIPCHILDREN = 0x2000000;
    public QuartzTypeLib.IMediaControl mc;
    public QuartzTypeLib.IVideoWindow videoWindow = null;
    IMediaPosition mp = null;
```

And here's the code that opens the video file:

```
    private void openMediaToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Open a media file.
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.Filter = "Video Files|*.mpg;*.avi;*;*.wmv;*.mov";
        ofd.FilterIndex = 1;
        if (DialogResult.OK == ofd.ShowDialog())
        { 
            // Stop the playback for the current movie if a video is currently playing.
            if (mc != null)
                mc.Stop();
            if (pbVideoDisplay.Image != null)
                pbVideoDisplay.Image = null;
            // Load the movie file.
            FilgraphManager graphManager = new FilgraphManager();
            graphManager.RenderFile(ofd.FileName);
            mp = graphManager as IMediaPosition;
            mc = (IMediaControl)graphManager;
            tsbtnPlay.Enabled = tsbtnPause.Enabled = tsbtnStop.Enabled = true;

            // Attach the view to the picture box (pbVideoDisplay) on frmMain.
            try
            {
                videoWindow = (IVideoWindow)graphManager;
                videoWindow.Owner = (int)pbVideoDisplay.Handle;
                videoWindow.WindowStyle = WS_CHILD | WS_CLIPCHILDREN;
                videoWindow.SetWindowPosition(
                pbVideoDisplay.ClientRectangle.Left,
                pbVideoDisplay.ClientRectangle.Top,
                pbVideoDisplay.ClientRectangle.Width,
                pbVideoDisplay.ClientRectangle.Height);
            }
            catch //(Exception Ex)
            {
                // I'll write code for this when I have a need to.
            }
            // Now we convert the video to a byte array.
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(ofd.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            try
            {
                // Here we convert the video to Base 64.
                VideoInBytes = new byte[fs.Length];
                VideoInBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ofd.FileName);
                VideoInBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(VideoInBytes);
            }
            catch //(Exception Ex)
            {
                //throw new Exception("Error in base64Encode" + Ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Notice that I have code that converts the video to a Base64 string. This string will obviously have to be loaded into a memory stream. I'd like to add code that will allow me to play a video from a memory stream. Is that even possible with DirectShow and if so, what code would I need to add and where would I put it?

Comment: Why would you do this, if you have the file on your harddisk? Anyway here is a similar question and an answer: ["Rendering from memory using DirectShow"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24476826/rendering-from-memory-using-directshow)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, CPlusSharp. The reason I want to play a video from a memory stream is because I have to store the video as a Base64 string. the video and a whole mess of other data must be saved into a single binary file so they can be uploaded and downloaded to/from various locations. I'll check out the link you provided. Thanks for the link too!

Comment: The way I would do this: pack the video and your metadata as a zip-file and extract it temporary on the client side. Base64 encoding a video needs more space (x 1.333)!

Answer (score 2):

The DirectShow way is to create a special so-called filter (source filter) that outputs video data and then add it to the graph chain.

Usually a filter is written in C++. Of course almost any code that can be written in C++ can be rewritten in C#. It could take a lot of work, for instance look at this article:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/421167/Pure-NET-DirectShow-Filters-in-Csharp

Another way is file emulation. In this case you would need 3rd party solution like [BoxedApp](https://www.boxedapp.com/encrypted_video_streaming.html).

The idea is to intercept some file functions like SetFilePointer and ReadFile, to provide data as it is written from a real file (but in fact it is read from memory).