# How to play avi file from memory in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, directshow.net

to keep it short all I'm trying to do is read the bytes from an avi file and play them back in VB.Net. I'm fine with using third party libraries and have been toying around with DirectShow.Net mostly, however everywhere I look seems to say that it is not possible to play a file from bytes/a memory-stream without knowing a fair amount of C/C++ to do some modification. I'd appreciate any tips you guys can provide!

Comment: Your findings are correct: there is no memory data playback available out of the box, so you either save to temporary file and play from there, or you use a third party solution or C++ modification.

Comment: Do you have any that you could recommend?

Comment: See [Rendering from memory using DirectShow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24476826/rendering-from-memory-using-directshow) and referenced links. Third party filters might exist, however I am not aware of any.

Comment: Also check this answer, it's about C#, but about similar scenario: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29677378/1480104